# Use a class or elemets tag to style them

Tags: html, css

Which is the right way to style different elements in a document:

**Class:**

```
    <style>
        .red {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>

    <h1 class="red">Hello, world!</h1>
    <p class="red">This is some text.</p>
```

**HTML tags:**

```
    <style>
        h1,
        p {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>

    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <p>This is some text.</p>
```

Comment: I would suggest the first one with class name!

Comment: That entirely depends on whether you want to style *all* h1s and ps or just specific ones to which you assigned classes. Either way, your class name should not be named after what the style looks like, but after the semantic meaning of the element.

Comment: No way is inherently “better” than the other, it all depends on what exactly you want to accomplish. What is _bad_ however is a class name `red` – a class should describe the _semantics_ of the elements it is applied to, not the _currently_ desired formatting. So a class named `warning` f.e. could be appropriate if that’s what you want to show with those elements – and if the _current_ color you want to show your warnings in, then you put `color:red` into your stylesheet. If at some point in the future you decide warnings should be displayed in blue instead, then you just change the `color`.

Comment: @deceze & CBroe: It's just an example and in my question and sample code my focus is on something else. In my real website I never name classes like this. Many thanks for the tip, anyway! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it depends. If the "red" class has a styling that is repeated many times across the site I would use the .red class (although that is not a good name for a class as it describes the aspect of the element, what happens if the graphic designer decides that the red elements are now green? your class won't make sense anymore)

Answer (score 1):

This ultimately depends on what you feel more comfortable with.

Usually I would recommend using classes to style your content. This is because you will probably end up using HTML tags like `p`, `div` and the like all over your website for different purposes. And you will probably also want them to look different depending on where they are used for what purpose. While it is possible to define rules that will give you the desired behavior, it is not really easy to do so and a nightmare to maintain. Think of rules that look like this:

```
div p div div p h1 a { font-family:sans-serif; }
```

Nobody knows what is going on there. This would be much easier if you had just assigned classes to the elements that make up your document. For example:

```
.maincontent .quotebox .caption { font-family:sans-serif; }
```

It is up to you how much you want to drill down with those classes. You can either just assign a class to a top level element (like `div`) and then define rules for child elements or you can add a class to each element and then define rules for nested classes.

What you should do is think about what sort of CSS structure you would like to have. I like to think of different classes in terms of what I want elements to convey (in terms of information) rather than what I want them to look like. Making `red` a class name is somewhat beside the point as this does not tell you anything about the element that it is applied to. Also you might want to color it green at some point and then there would be elements of class `red` that are actually styled green. Better class names would IMHO be `navigation` or `maincontent` or `infobox`.

Answer (score 0):

I think style using `class` is better than style using `html tags.`

`class` have more privilage than `html tags` while providing style. if we use both the style provided in `class` taken.